# Installing GNU parallel without root permission

Tags: linux, bash, unix, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

**EDIT 2**

After trying to run parallel, I am getting the following on the terminal when I run both `parallel` and by the source `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin/parallel`:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Note: the process is still running even after the above output.

**EDIT 1**:

My pwd is `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424` and I ran

- `./configure --prefix=/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel` (note- I created the folder parallel)
- `make`
- `make install`

However, after everything, now when I try to run `parallel` it says `bash: parallel: command not found`.

For reference, after I ran the 3 commands,it gave the following output for each of the three steps:

1. Step 1:

`/configure:`

```
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
```

2. Step 2:

`make`

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
pod2man --release='20100424' --center='parallel' \
        --section=1 ./parallel > ./parallel.1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424'


I am trying to install GNU's parallel on a server where I don't have access to sudo. I downloaded parallel , used SCP to transfer from local to server, and as per read me I have to do three steps to install:
```

3. Step3:

`make install`

```
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
test -z "/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin"
 /usr/bin/install -c parallel '/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin'
test -z "/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/share/man/man1" || /bin/mkdir -p "/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/share/man/man1"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 parallel.1 '/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/share/man/man1'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424'
make[2]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424'
```

---

**Original question:**

1. ./configure
2. make
3. make install

I have successfully done the first 2 steps but in the 3rd step, that is `make install`, it gives the following error:

```
making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
 /usr/bin/install -c parallel '/usr/local/bin'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/parallel': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-binSCRIPTS] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel-20100424/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I think the main line is

`/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file /usr/local/bin/parallel': Permission denied`

I wanted to change the instance of this path in all files that contain it to a path which can be accessed without sudo or root permissions. However, when I try grep, I find no files that contain it.

```
grep -r "/usr/local/bin/parallel" *
```

What can I do now? Or, how can I possibly install parallel without root permissions?

I tried checking [this](http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html) but still didn't help.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `install` target is going to try to install the compiled program into `/usr/local/bin`, but you do not have permission to install it there. Did you try what the doc you mention suggests? `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried it, could you please check my new edit?

Comment: The Perl warning is not  preventing `parallel` from executing. If you want to avoid the warning, make sure your locale is properly configured. This is a very common Perl FAQ which should be easy to find in google.

Comment: Yes I just got that. That is not my priority. I just need parallel to be running. Any ideas why it might not be working?

Answer (score 5):

```
./configure --prefix=<target>
```

This will make the installation in `<target>/bin`, `<target>/lib` etc.; just do the `make install` as usual.

Choose a `<target>` you have access to (something in `${HOME}` if need be), and adjust your `PATH` to include `<target>/bin` (and, perhaps, `MANPATH` to include `<target>/share/man` so you get access to the man pages as well).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it. Could you please check my new edit?

Comment: @HackCode: You need to, and I quote, "adjust your `PATH` to include `<target>/bin`". That'd be `export PATH=$PATH:/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin`. You probably want to add that line to your `.bashrc` or somesuch.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I also tried adding `export PATH="/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin/:$PATH"` and repeated the three steps, still no luck. :/

Comment: @HackCode: Please show the output of `ls /homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin/`.

Comment: output is `parallel`, that is, there is only one file.

Comment: It is in green color.

Comment: Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Well, if there's an executable `parallel` in `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin/`, and that directory is also included in `PATH` (that means, *you added it to PATH in the very same shell session you're trying to call it from*), then there should be no way for you to get `parallel: command not found`. Try calling it with the full path, `/homedtic/gsantamaria/parallel/bin/parallel`.

Comment: Hello thanks for your comment. Could you please check my EDIT2 for the output of what you asked me to run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87386/discussion-between-hackcode-and-devsolar).

Answer (score 4):

If you have conda, `conda install -c conda-forge parallel` is also a one-line solution.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using linuxbrew (http://linuxbrew.sh)

```
brew install parallel
```

Comment: +1, this works nicely for parallel, it is a good solution because you avoid to compile everything from source.

Answer (score 1):

The script
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/10seconds_install first tries an install requiring root; then a personal installation and if that fails too: a minimal installation.

It might just work for you out of the box, and if not, then it might serve as inspiration.

Answer (score -1):

This did it for me, without root access:

```
(wget pi.dk/3 -qO - ||  curl pi.dk/3/) | bash
```

See [this link](http://oletange.blogspot.de/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html).

Comment: wgetting a script from an unknown server and piping it directly to bash? What if pi.dk/3 change the script?

Comment: That's a valid point. you can also just download the script from pi.dk/3 now, and post it here as an answer. The script simply downloads the latest version of GNU Parallel, checks the signature and installs it.