# Can you help me run tasks in parallel in Slurm?

Tags: bash, slurm, sbatch

I am new to Slurm and I trying to launch several executables to run in parallel (in the example below it is just the date command). I would like them to start at different times, separated by a short time delay.

I have made a few attemps, trying to add additional lines in between the sruns, such as "srun sleep 5s &" or with the "--begin" option shown below. In particular, the "--begin" option fails saying that "--begin is ignored because nodes are already allocated".

The parallel module seems not to be available in our cluster.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output=parallel_test_%j.out   # Standard output and error log
#SBATCH --time=06:00:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1   # number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks=6   
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1024M   # memory per CPU core

srun="srun -n1 -N1 --exclusive"
# --exclusive     ensures srun uses distinct CPUs for each job step
# -N1 -n1         allocates a single core to each task


$srun date &
$srun --begin=now+3 date &
$srun --begin=now+6 date &
$srun --begin=now+9 date &
$srun --begin=now+12 date &
$srun --begin=now+15 date &
wait
```

The output I get is the following:

```
srun: error: --begin is ignored because nodes are already allocated.
srun: error: --begin is ignored because nodes are already allocated.
srun: error: --begin is ignored because nodes are already allocated.
srun: error: --begin is ignored because nodes are already allocated.
srun: error: --begin is ignored because nodes are already allocated.
Sun Jun 23 14:07:05 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 14:07:05 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 14:07:05 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 14:07:05 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 14:07:05 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 14:07:06 PDT 2019
```

What I would like to obtain is the following output:

```
Sun Jun 23 13:22:54 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 13:22:57 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 13:23:00 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 13:23:03 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 13:23:06 PDT 2019
Sun Jun 23 13:23:09 PDT 2019
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) correctly points out that your `srun` variable is unused. Did you mean `$srun date &`?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was definitely missing the $ symbol. Still, I am not getting the output desired...

Comment: You can set up delays between srun calls (`sleep 5`). But what is the rational for this? It does not seem to be useful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `--begin` will be of no help because it is used to defer the initiation of the job, and the job already started when `srun` is run in the submission script.

You can get the requested behaviour like this:

```
$srun date &
sleep 3; $srun date &
sleep 3; $srun date &
sleep 3; $srun date &
sleep 3; $srun date &
sleep 3; $srun date &
wait
```

or even like this

```
$srun date &
$srun bash -c "sleep 3 ; date" &
$srun bash -c "sleep 6 ; date" &
$srun bash -c "sleep 9 ; date" &
$srun bash -c "sleep 12 ; date" &
$srun bash -c "sleep 15 ; date" &
wait
```

Regarding

> The parallel module seems not to be available in our cluster

that does not mean you cannot install it by yourself (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093425/installing-gnu-parallel-without-root-permission)). If [Easybuild](https://easybuild.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is installed on your cluster, it is even easier. (If it is not, you can also install it by yourself) Then you can use the `--delay` option.

```
parallel --delay 3 $srun date
```