# parallel computing in multiple cores for data which is indepedently run with the program

Tags: parallel-processing

I have a simulation program in fortran which takes the input from a .dat. This file has 100.000 lines which takes really long to run. The program take the first line, run all the simulations and write in a .out the result and pass to the next line. I have a computer with 16 cpu so how can I do to split my data in 16 parts and run it separatly in each of the cpus? I am running in a machine with ubuntu. It is totally independent each line from the other.
For example my data is HeadData10000.dat, then I have a file simulation.ini with the name of the input data in this case: HeadData10000.dat and with the name of the output data. So the file simulation.ini will look like that

```
HeadData10000.dat
outputdata.out
```

Then now I have two computer so I split my HeadData10000.dat y two files and I do two simulation.ini for each input data and I run it like this in each computer: ./simulation.exe<./simulation.ini.

Comment: Is the processing of each line entirely independent of the processing of previous lines? I mean, would it still work if the lines in the data file were entered in reverse order?

Comment: I don't know how it could be done in Fortran, but generally this could be solved by using *threads* and *thread pools* (if the data of each input-line is independent).

Comment: If the processing of each line is independent of previous lines, you can very easily use **GNU Parallel**, excellent PDF here... https://zenodo.org/record/1146014/files/GNU_Parallel_2018.pdf?download=1  You need `--pipe-part` parameter. Please give a few lines of your data file and how you would run fortran code for one of the lines. Edit your question, do not put code in comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of 100,000 jobs is called `"jobs.txt"` and looks like this:

```
JobA
JobB
JobC
JobD
```

You could run this:

```
parallel 'printf "{}\n{.}.out" | ./simulation.exe' < jobs.txt
```

If you want to do a dry run to see what that would do without doing anything:

```
parallel --dry-run 'printf "{}\n{.}.out" | ./simulation.exe' < jobs.txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
printf "JobA\nJobA.out" | ./simulation.exe
printf "JobB\nJobB.out" | ./simulation.exe
printf "JobC\nJobC.out" | ./simulation.exe
printf "JobD\nJobD.out" | ./simulation.exe
```

If you have multiple servers available, look at using the `-S` parameter to **GNU Parallel** to spread the jobs across the machines. Also, look at the `--eta` and `--bar` parameters for getting progress reports.

I used `printf "line1 \n line2"` to generate two lines of input in order to avoid having to create, and later delete 100,000 files.

By default, **GNU Parallel** will keep 1 job per CPU core running, so there will always be 16 jobs running on your 16-core machine, but you can change that to, say, 8 if you want to with `parallel -j 8`. You can also specify the number of jobs to run on your second (and subsequent) machines.

Comment: The server does not have installed GNU so I can't use this command. However, I tried it in my own machine and it is super useful, thanks!

Comment: See a 10second easy install of **GNU Parallel** without root access here from Ole Tange, the author of GNU Parallel... https://stackoverflow.com/a/42396008/2836621

Comment: Thanks  but the problem is that I don't have permission to install anything in the server.

Comment: Read https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/ - especially the part about `--embed`.